# Access ref of component in another component?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

In my component `Box` I return a `mesh` which is of type `Object3d`, I need to get a reference to this object in my `Floor` component but I haven't figured out a way to do this. I tried to assign another ref in my `App` component and pass it to `Floor` but this way I only get `{current: undefined}`.

How can I reference the `mesh` ref of `Box` in another component?

This is how I tried it

```
export default function App() {

  const box = useRef();

  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 10, 10] }} onCreated={({ scene }) => {
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, 0, 750);
    }} >
      <hemisphereLight args={[0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75]} position={[0.5, 1, 0.75]}></hemisphereLight>
      <Box ref={box} position={[0, 10, -30]} />
      <Floor boxRef={box}></Floor>
    </Canvas>
  )
}

function Floor({ boxRef }) {
  const mesh = useRef();

  useFrame(() => {
    // How to use the mesh ref of Box here?????
    console.log(boxRef);
  })

  return (
    <mesh ref={mesh} >
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[2000, 2000]} rotateX={-Math.PI / 2}></planeBufferGeometry>
      <meshStandardMaterial color="#999999"></meshStandardMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function Box(props) {
  const mesh = useRef()
  
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}>
      <boxBufferGeometry args={[20, 20, 20]} />
      <meshPhongMaterial color={0x00ff00}></meshPhongMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should not override ref in Box component and just use {...props}

```
export default function App() {

  const box = useRef();

  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 10, 10] }} onCreated={({ scene }) => {
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, 0, 750);
    }} >
      <hemisphereLight args={[0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75]} position={[0.5, 1, 0.75]}></hemisphereLight>
      <Box ref={box} position={[0, 10, -30]} />
      <Floor boxRef={box}></Floor>
    </Canvas>
  )
}

function Floor({ boxRef }) {
  const mesh = useRef();

  useFrame(() => {
    // How to use the mesh ref of Box here?????
    console.log(boxRef);
  })

  return (
    <mesh ref={mesh} >
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[2000, 2000]} rotateX={-Math.PI / 2}></planeBufferGeometry>
      <meshStandardMaterial color="#999999"></meshStandardMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
}

function Box(props) {
  
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}>
      <boxBufferGeometry args={[20, 20, 20]} />
      <meshPhongMaterial color={0x00ff00}></meshPhongMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did not quite solved the issue but it got the right direction. I had to use `React.forwardRef` for it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involved `React.forwardRef`, this is how I solved it

```
export default function App() {

  const box = useRef();

  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 10, 10] }} onCreated={({ scene }) => {
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
      scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0xffffff, 0, 750);
    }} >
      <hemisphereLight args={[0xeeeeff, 0x777788, 0.75]} position={[0.5, 1, 0.75]}></hemisphereLight>
      <Box ref={box} position={[0, 10, -30]} />
      <Floor boxRef={box}></Floor>
    </Canvas>
  )
}

function Floor({ boxRef }) {
  const mesh = useRef();

  useFrame(() => {
    console.log(boxRef);
  })

  return (
    <mesh ref={mesh} >
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[2000, 2000]} rotateX={-Math.PI / 2}></planeBufferGeometry>
      <meshStandardMaterial color="#999999"></meshStandardMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
}

const Box = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {  
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={ref}>
      <boxBufferGeometry args={[20, 20, 20]} />
      <meshPhongMaterial color={0x00ff00}></meshPhongMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
})
```